# Laravel 5 : Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

http://localhost/laravel/tests/ExampleTest.php
if i run laravel it shows the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in
>   /var/www/html/laravel/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 3

Comment: You dont run test case from http. Try intalling phpunit. Run with it.

Comment: You cannot link files on your localhost. Please post the code here, instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep in mind from next on wards.

Answer (score 3):

To run tests you should install `phpunit`:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Then cd to the project folder and run `phpunit`:

```
cd /var/www/html/laravel/
phpunit
```

Output should be something like this:

> PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .........E.....................EEEEE                              36 /
>   36 (100%)
>
> Time: 1.84 seconds, Memory: 104.02Mb

Answer (score 1):

You can not run your tests from the web browser, you need to use [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de) on the command line instead.

Are you using [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead)? If so you will have PHPUnit installed on that machine.

Laravel specific testing information can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/testing) and PHPUnit docs can be found [here](https://phpunit.de/documentation.html).